# Touch and Drag in Flash CC AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, touch, drag

I'm only learning AS3 this year, I need to be able to turn my key events into touch and drag events to export my game to iOS everything in my app works fine except for the paddle which I need to be able to touch and drag horizontally. Any help is appreciated here is my code for the paddle key events.

```
    private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.A) 
        {
            //1st Player Left Key
            p1speed = -1;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            //1st Player Right Key
            p1speed = 1;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) 
        {
            spacePressed = true;
        }
    }

    private function keyUpHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if ((evt.keyCode == Keyboard.A) || (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.D))
        {
            p1speed = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use Touch and Drag Events you are going to have to implement the following code:

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
```

then in your MainFunction where you declare your variables you would add this piece of code:

```
    //MultiTouch added for touch gestures
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

In your constructor Function:

```
            //setup Listeners when btn's touch begin and end
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true); 
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true);
```

the functions that control the Events:

```
private function btnUpMouseOver(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {
        //trace("btnUpRollOver");
          if (e.type == TouchEvent.)
          {
              //Mouse was pressed on this button
              btnPressedUp = true;



          }
          else if(e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_END)
          {
              //Mouse was released
              btnPressedUp = false;
          }
    }
```

You can also refer to this:  [Adobe Touch EVents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffc.html)